# rails name convention for service objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions

Usually I use **nouns** when I give names to my classes.
I gave a **noun derived from a verb** like '**worker**' or '**purchaser**' as name for my **service objects**.
During a code review it was said that it is common to gave **verbs as names** for service objects like '**work**' '**purchase**'.

Which direction should I follow?

Here is another oppinion against **verbs**:

> Mostly it doesn't make sense from a standpoint of clarity and natural
>   language to use verbs. Let's say you have model Product and you want a
>   service object that will handle pricing on some complex criteria
>   (geolocation, color, shipping, moonphase, etc). It would be a good
>   candidate for a service object ProductPricingService. You wouldn't
>   just call it Price or Pricing. First of all it's ambigious. Pricing of
>   what? Products that you sell? Pricing you get from vendors? Pricing of
>   gas today? And if you were to argue that this Service object could be
>   used by many models, then you are defeating the purpose of Service
>   Object. I'm exaggerating of course. But the whole point is to create
>   clear and maintainable code. So while you can save some keystrokes by
>   naming it Price, it's much more clear to another person ( and you in 5
>   months) if you name it ProductPricingService.

Here is an oppinion against **deverbal nouns**

> You can use something like InvoiceFinder instead of FindInvoice, but I
>   found out that putting the action at the end led to awkward named
>   classes, so putting the verb at the beginning made them cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your original one, using deverbal nouns makes more sense. You should use verbs for method names.

Comment: This is another answer I received from another forum:

You can use something like InvoiceFinder instead of FindInvoice, but I found out that putting the action at the end led to awkward named classes, so putting the verb at the beginning made them cleaner.

Comment: Object at the beginning (verb after) feels like it makes it easier to scan as you start to have a ton of service objects